# Play Billing Library impide cargar mi aplicación creada con Expo

Tags: android, google-play, expo, google-play-console, google-app-billing

Tengo una aplicación creada con Expo a la que recientemente actualicé los `SDK`, esto quiere decir que no tengos archivos de configuración de Android.

La App no ​​vende productos, solo tiene una pantalla o sección donde se muestran algunos artículos que tienen con un boton que da la posibilidad de ir a la tienda de productos.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';


export default function Store(props) {

  const contextState = React.useContext(LanguageContext);
  const language = contextState.language;
  const Strings = Languages[language].texts;
  
  const onChangeScreen = (screen) => {
    props.navigation.navigate(screen);
  };

 return (

  <ScrollView
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
>
    
<SafeAreaView>

    <View style={Styles.StoreScreen}>

    <Heading title={Strings.ST69}/>
    <FeaturedProducts/>

    <Heading title={Strings.ST71} button={() => onChangeScreen('types')}/>
    <ProductTypes/>

    <Heading title={Strings.ST70} button={() => onChangeScreen('products')}/>
    <LatestProducts/>

    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>

      );

}
```

Pero no se venden productos en la Aplicació, solo mostramos el enlace a la tienda.

Cuando intento subirlo a Google Play Console, me impide hacerlo por los siguientes motivos:

**Error
Hemos detectado que uno o más de los paquetes de aplicaciones incluidos en esta versión utilizan las siguientes versiones de la biblioteca de facturación de Play.
4.1.0
Estas son versiones no compatibles de Facturación de Google Play. Actualice a una versión compatible para publicar esta aplicación.**

**Error
Esta aplicación está dirigida a Android 14 y versiones posteriores. Su versión actual de Play Billing Library no es compatible con Android 14. Para apuntar a la última versión de Android, actualice su versión de Play Billing Library a la versión 5.2.1, 6.0.1 o posterior.**

Con las indicaciones del otro usuario, he buscado las dependencias, sin exito, incluidas la dependencias de `node_modules`

No sé cómo encontrar las dependencias que pueda tener mi aplicación de esta biblioteca. La única referencia a todo lo relacionado con facturación es la siguiente:

```
public function __construct($data = NULL) {
\GPBMetadata\Google\Api\Billing::initOnce();
parent::__construct($data);
}
```

¿Pueden orientarme un poco con este error?

Como se trata de una aplicación `Expo`, no tenemos otros archivos de configuración de Andriod.

```
{
  "name": "ejercicio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.8.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^6.7.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.13",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "2.2.0",
    "expo": "^50.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~9.0.2",
    "expo-av": "~13.10.4",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.11.0",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.7",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.8.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~12.8.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~6.4.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.24.9",
    "expo-video-player": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "hex-to-rgba": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-inviewport": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.11.4",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Y muestro el aap.json
Hice algunos cambios que encontre [en otra consulta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73228675/submitting-expo-app-bundle-to-google-play-unsupported-version-of-play-billing?rq=2) del sitio, pero no funciono.

Añadi esto:
"permissions": ["com.android.vending.BILLING"]

Cree otra aab, pero no hubo exito
Este es el archivo:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "appName",
    "slug": "appName",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "version": "4.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/ebf31c70-d4dd-11e9-a89d-e9a1a09d86a3"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "3",
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxxxx",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "requireFullScreen": true
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 4,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.xxxxxxxxx",
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "com.android.vending.BILLING"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "29a917ff-6189-439d-80a1-ba206031243d",
        "build": {
          "experimental": {
            "ios": {
              "appExtensions": [
               
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tienes que actualizar la versión de la biblioteca Google Play Billing en el build.gradle a mínimo 6.0.1., revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: No es una app, Google App Billing es una dependencia que usa la app.

Comment: Entonces de acuerdo a lo que comentas "solo tiene una sección donde hay algunos artículos que tienen la posibilidad de ir a la tienda de productos", no usas en realidad la biblioteca, revisa en los build.gradle de tu proyecto si tienes "com.android.billingclient:billing" y elimina la línea, si no se usa tu proyecto funcionaría sin problema

Comment: Efectivamente solo hay una sección donde pongo productos con enlace a la tienda del producto. Y no hay `build.gradle`porque el proyecto esta construido unicamente con Expo. No hay referencias en todo el proyecto a `billingclient` ni nada relacionado con `Google Play Billing Library`. No se que mas puedo hacer. Lamentablemente tu respuesta no es util, aunque me sirvio para buscar y descartar opciones.

Comment: Hola @MiguelEspeso} tienes un archivo app.json o eas.json en tu proyecto para agregarlo a tu pregunta. ?

Comment: Ya lo añadi. Antes, hice unas pruebas basandome en una respuesta de hace 2 años en stackoverflow, pero cree el `aab` usando `eas build`pero Google me muestra el mis o error. Esto es muy descorcentante

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto al primer mensaje de error:

> "Error Hemos detectado que uno o más de los paquetes de aplicaciones
> incluidos en esta versión utilizan las siguientes versiones de la
> biblioteca de facturación de Play. 4.1.0 Estas son versiones no
> compatibles de Facturación de Google Play. Actualice a una versión
> compatible para publicar esta aplicación."

en inglés:

> We've detected that one or more of the app bundles included in this
> release are using the following Play Billing Library versions
> 4.1.0 These are unsupported versions of Google Play Billing. Upgrade to a supported version to publish this app.

**El problema se debe a que las versiones de `Google Play Billing Library` menores a 5.0 son obsoletas desde el 1 de noviembre de 2023**, por lo que debes actualizar esta biblioteca y realizar los cambios necesarios. Debiste incluso recibir un email de aviso sobre esto, ejemplo: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con respecto al segundo mensaje de error:

> "Error Esta aplicación está dirigida a Android 14 y versiones
> posteriores. Su versión actual de `Play Billing Library` no es
> compatible con Android 14. Para apuntar a la última versión de
> Android, actualice su versión de Play Billing Library a la versión
> 5.2.1, 6.0.1 o posterior."

Es muy importante saber que **si vas a compilar tu aplicación orientada a Android 14 o posterior, debes actualizar tu aplicación para usar como minimo [`Google Play Billing Library` 6.0.1](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes?hl=es-419#6-0-1)**

Por lo tanto, **para solucionar ambos casos, debes actualizar como minimo a Google Play Billling Library 6.0.1**

```
'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1'
```

---

Puedes revisar con mayor detalle los cambios de  `Google Play Billing` en la documentación:

[**Notas de la versión de la biblioteca de Google Play Billing**](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes?hl=es-419)

Revisa sobre este cambio ne la documentación de [**Expo**](https://github.com/expo/expo) :

[**Compras expo-in-app: actualice la versión de Google Play Billing Library a versión 5.0 o superior**](https://forums.expo.dev/t/google-billing-library/52036)